# Rotate logs weekly with a week number in the log's name

Tags: linux, shell, logging, logrotate

I am setting up `logrotate` and would like to rotate some logs weekly, preferably on Mondays, and have their names changed to `example-%year%.w%weeknumber%`, where `%weeknumber%` is a number of the week in a given year.

The logrotate with my configuration will be run daily by adding a file similar to [logrotate.cron](https://github.com/logrotate/logrotate/blob/master/examples/logrotate.cron) to `/etc/cron.daily/`. My logrotate configuration looks like this:

```
rotate 12
dateext
nocompress

/var/logs/example* {
    weekly
    dateformat .%Y-w%W
}
```

The `%W` in the config is based on [strftime](https://linux.die.net/man/3/strftime) format. However, running a test `logrotate -df /etc/logrotate.d/myconf.conf` results in the following output:

```
(...)
considering log /var/logs/example
Creating new state
  Now: 2020-04-23 00:18
  Last rotated at 2020-04-23 00:00
  log needs rotating
rotating log /var/logs/example, log->rotateCount is 12
Converted ' .%Y-w%W' -> '.%Y-w%%W'
dateext suffix '.2020-w%W'
glob pattern '.[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]-w%W'
glob finding old rotated logs failed
renaming /var/logs/example to /var/logs/example.2020-w%W
(...)
```

That means, instead of the week number, I would get literally `%W` in its place. The same happens with `%U` when placed instead of `%W`.

I am using logrotate 3.11.0 since it is the newest one available via `zypper` on the machine I want to set this up.

How can I make `logrotate` use an actual week number when renaming log files?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using `%V` instead of `%U` or `%W` did the trick for me.

```
rotate 12
dateext
nocompress

/var/logs/example* {
    weekly
    dateformat .%Y-w%V
}
```

According to manual pages for `strftime`:

> **%V** The ISO 8601  week  number (see NOTES) of the current year as a decimal number, range 01 to 53, where week 1 is the  first  week that  has  at least 4 days in the new year.  See also %U and %W. (Calculated from tm_year, tm_yday, and tm_wday.)

Also, according to [man entry for 3.11.0](https://github.com/logrotate/logrotate/blob/3.11.0/logrotate.8.in) (which I had somehow missed before asking this question):

> Only %Y %m %d %H %M %S %V and %s specifiers are allowed.

The `%V` itself was added in 3.9.0.

Although this question regards an older version of logrotate, use the newest, whenever possible.

Comment: `logrotate`' 3.11 behavior is somehow, hm, bugged, when renaming older files. In my case, 4 weeks of weekly rotations resulted in... 32 files, instead of 5. Only five of these files weren't empty.

Comment: FWIW, it was the configuration that was wrong - `example*` glob is too extensive and matches also already rotated files. Fixed by changing it to `example*[!0-9]`.